# Merging and combining two arrays in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have two arrays one created from a table in my database and one created from a HTML form (lets call them **`array_db`** and **`array_form`**).

I want to insert **`array_db`** to a table in my **mySQL** database, but before inserting I must merge **`array_db`** with **`array_form`** and remove duplicates. When there are a duplicates I want the values from **`array_form`** to be inserted to **`array_db`**

**NOTE**: **`array_form`** are not always the same meaning it could have more or less values than in the below ex.

What is the best way to do this?

**Array_db**

```
Array
(
    [task_id] => task_id
)
Array
(
    [user_id] => user_id
)
Array
(
    [customer_id] => customer_id
)
Array
(
    [created] => created
)
Array
(
    [pickup] => pickup
)
Array
(
    [tire_front] => tire_front
)
Array
(
    [tire_back] => tire_back
)
Array
(
    [tire_reg] => tire_reg
)
Array
(
    [tire_indl] => tire_indl
)
Array
(
    [tube_front] => tube_front
)
Array
(
    [tube_back] => tube_back
)
Array
(
    [hub_front] => hub_front
)
Array
(
    [hub_back] => hub_back
)
Array
(
    [hub_adjust] => hub_adjust
)
Array
(
    [rim_front] => rim_front
)
Array
(
    [rim_back] => rim_back
)
Array
(
    [rim_adjust] => rim_adjust
)
Array
(
    [spoke_missing_front] => spoke_missing_front
)
Array
(
    [spoke_missing_back] => spoke_missing_back
)
Array
(
    [spoke_comp_front] => spoke_comp_front
)
Array
(
    [spoke_comp_back] => spoke_comp_back
)
Array
(
    [break_adjust_front] => break_adjust_front
)
Array
(
    [break_adjust_back] => break_adjust_back
)
Array
(
    [break_cable_front] => break_cable_front
)
Array
(
    [break_cable_back] => break_cable_back
)
Array
(
    [break_pad_front] => break_pad_front
)
Array
(
    [break_pad_back] => break_pad_back
)
Array
(
    [gear_adj_front] => gear_adj_front
)
Array
(
    [gear_adj_back] => gear_adj_back
)
Array
(
    [gear_cable_front] => gear_cable_front
)
Array
(
    [gear_cable_back] => gear_cable_back
)
Array
(
    [gear_shift_front] => gear_shift_front
)
Array
(
    [gear_shift_back] => gear_shift_back
)
Array
(
    [bicy_chain] => bicy_chain
)
Array
(
    [cog_wheel] => cog_wheel
)
Array
(
    [cassette] => cassette
)
Array
(
    [chainwheel] => chainwheel
)
Array
(
    [crankset] => crankset
)
Array
(
    [crank] => crank
)
Array
(
    [fp_service] => fp_service
)
Array
(
    [status] => status
)
Array
(
    [service_1] => service_1
)
Array
(
    [service_2] => service_2
)
Array
(
    [service_3] => service_3
)
Array
(
    [service_4] => service_4
)
Array
(
    [price_approx] => price_approx
)
Array
(
    [price_max] => price_max
)
```

**Array_form**

```
(
[tire_back] => tire_back
[tube_back] => tube_back
[gear_shift_front] => gear_shift_front
[user_id] => 0
[customer_id] => 6
)
```

Comment: Flatten `array_db` and then [`array_merge()`](http://php.net/array_merge) as "_If the input arrays have the same string keys, then the later value for that key will overwrite the previous one._"

Comment: To whom -1 this question. Why did this question deserve a -1? please explain.

Comment: I -1'd for one main reason: You did not attempt anything (or maybe you did but neither said nor showed what). And as I stated in my other comment, the answer is quite trivial. This implies that you encountered the problem and instead of trying to solve it yourself, you directly came here for an answer, so you got the -1

Comment: ... @kingkero You are assuming I did not do anything. I do not post questions in this forum unless I have tried Google, talked to friends and tested myself. Unfortunately I got no working results. Please do not give questions a -1 based on your assumptions -> ask instead.

Comment: Please show that and what you previously tried, so I don't have to ask ;) That aside, have you tried what I suggested in the first comment?

Comment: ... @kingkero - Your questions could might solve my problem or have me re-think ;-) Stack Overflow is a **question** and **answer** site. I tried several solutions, and putting them in this questions would have become a jungle of code, therefore I chose not to and instead asked and show some code as simple as I could. Reg. your answer/suggestion, I have changed my code because of DB reasons + I unfortunately never did figured out (despite lots of Googling/testing) how to flatten my array in my question. If you have a link or ex. on how to flatten an array, please share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my comment, this should be solveable by first flattening `$array_db`, eg like this

```
$flat_array_db = array();
foreach ($array_db as $subArray) {
    foreach ($subArray as $key=>$value) {
        $flat_array_db[$key] = $value;
    }
}
```

And once you've done that, a simple `array_merge($flat_array_db, $array_form)` should do the trick.

Comment: ...Thank you @kingkero I will look into your suggestion. I appreciate you are taking your time to help me.